# Error Loading SoX

Tags: sound, sox

I use a really useful tool called r128gain which performs loudness normalisation on audio files.
Under 17.10, however, I get the following error however...

```
Failed opening "/home/Downloads/r128gain-1.0.11-linux64-gtk3/r128gain-tools/libsox.so.2".
Error loading SoX.
```

Can anybody shed any light on this for me, I would love to get it working again?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the tool is missing the `sox`installation

`sudo apt-get install sox`

should fix it

---

Edit: Installing alone did not fix it, you have to tell **r128gain** where to look for the sox library

```
mv /home/username/r128gain-1.0.11-linux64-gtk3/r128gain-tools/libsox.so.2 /home/username/r128gain-1.0.11-linux64-gtk3/r128gain-tools/libsox.so.2_backup

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsox.so.2 /home/username/r128gain-1.0.11-linux64-gtk3/r128gain-tools/libsox.so.2
```

Then it works

```
./r128gain  /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wavSoX sucessfully loaded.
FFmpeg sucessfully loaded.
analyzing ...
  [1/1] "Noise.wav": -29.7 LUFS (6.7 LU)
      peak: -17.9 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
  [ALBUM]: -29.7 LUFS (6.7 LU)
      peak: -17.9 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
done.
```

Answer (score 2):

SoX executable in `r128gain-1.0.11-linux64-gtk3/r128gain-tools` depends on libpng12 (not exist in modern Ubuntu), so we need to install it manually:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.49-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.49-1+deb7u2_amd64.deb
```

After this it works:

```
artful@artful:~/Downloads/r128gain-1.0.11-linux64-gtk3$ ./r128gain  /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav SoX sucessfully loaded.
FFmpeg sucessfully loaded.
analyzing ...
  [1/1] "Noise.wav": -29.7 LUFS (6.7 LU)
      peak: -17.9 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
  [ALBUM]: -29.7 LUFS (6.7 LU)
      peak: -17.9 TPFS, range: 0.0 LU
done.
```

Comment: you don't need to install debian packages, ubuntu already brings sox and a working sox library

Comment: We do not know build flags of libsox built by r128gain. So I leave my answer here. Copying parts of my answer is not good manner.

Comment: I'm very happy to have it working again, thank you both for taking the time to answer. :)